# Global EditText Variables

Tags: java, android

I'm writing my first android app, and I have an EditText object that I want to be read across my entire program (multiple activities). I'd like to take in a user's name on one screen/activity/layout and read it in several others to manipulate or display it, so I've found that the string needs to be public and static, and that there should be a class with my global variables. What is the correct way to do this? I've tried using bundles and several other methods, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely be passing this value through intents.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NEXTCLASS.class);
        intent.putExtra("username",mEditText1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
```

and then to receive it in the next class

```
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        mEditText1.setText(extras.getString("username"))
```

You could also use shared preferences however I think that is unnecessary for your situation as you do not need the username to persist when the app is closed.

Update:

To use shared prefs..

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("username", myusername);
```

To read from shared prefs...

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
```

An example of using a static property

```
public class utility {
    public static String USERNAME = "username";
}
```

To invoke you do not need to instantiate the class just do this from each class that needs it

```
String username = sharedPreferences.getString(utility.USERNAME, "")
```

Comment: Do you happen to have an example for SharedPrefs? Persistence was my next step, using shared prefs would be perfect.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of how to use shared preferences.

Comment: Thanks! This seems perfect! One last question - can the shared pref string "username" be put into a class, and then made public so that I don't have to reread the shared pref in each .java file?

Comment: You can make a class with a static property called username or maybe make an enum class as well

Comment: Updated my question to show how to create and use a static property.

Comment: Mike has basically covered all the ways to use global variables outside of using a database (which probably isnt what you want to do)

Comment: If I have an edittext field, do I have to save the text, or does it save as a preference/variable as soon as I type it in?

Comment: This method worked flawlessly. I wasn't receiving data across the application, not because of the way I was transferring data, but rather because the way I took text in from edittext to string was incorrect. I made a constant andfound that the data was transported across the entire program. I have to fix edittext

Comment: I am glad you were able to get your code working. Please accept my answer if it helped you figure out your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store the value. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).